# how do I access the servlet results from an iFrame?

Tags: iframe, gson

I am using javascript. I use an iframe to upload a file to a servlet . I use a java servlet that correctly receives the post and returns a gson object. However I cannot access the returned object from the iframe.

Here is the form

```
<form name='myform' id='myform' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:9090/myServlet" target="myFrame" > 
<td> <input type="file" size=20 name="fname"> </td> 
<td> <input type="Submit" value="Upload"> </td> </form> 
</tr></table>
<iframe src="" id="myFrame" name="myFrame" style="width: 110px; height: 110px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var accountList=null;
    </script>
</iframe>
```

the servlet does whatever it needs and returns

```
 > response.setContentType("text/html");
    > response.getWriter().println("<html><body
    > onload=\"window.parent.uploadComplete();\">"+
    >                     "<div id='resu' name='resu'>" +
    >                     gsonTable+
    >                     "</div>"+
    >                     "</body></html>");     response.getWriter().close();
```

where the gsonTable is {"nickname":"defaultStatname","date":"1/1/2010/"}

how do I get the gson object off the div?

In my function

```
function uploadComplete() {
    var frame=parent.document.getElementById('myFrame');
    var pippo=frame.contentDocument;
    var div = pippo.getElementById('resu');
    var myvar=div.innerHTML;
    myvar=eval(myvar); }
```

when I perform eval(myvar) I get "invalid label"
I am quite surprised because being a gson object it should be fine to eval the string. 
I am sure I am making a mistake somewhere but I cannot find it. Maybe I should not store the gson object in the div at all and there is a better solution. 
Any help would be great
/f

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I think I have been pretty naive here. 
I declare a variable in the iframe and assign it in the servlet to the gson variable within the iFrame html. Then I read the variable within the uploadComplete function. Here it is

```
<form name='myform' id='myform' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:9090/bankUI/loadaccountstatement" target="myFrame" > 
<td> <input type="file" size=20 name="fname"> </td> 

<td> <input type="Submit" value="Upload"> </td> </form> 
</tr></table>
<iframe src="" id="myFrame" name="myFrame" style="width: 110px; height: 110px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var newStatement;
    </script>
</iframe>
```

the servlet code:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
                        response.getWriter().println("<html><body onload=\"window.parent.uploadComplete();\">"+
                                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                                "parent.document.newStatement = "+gsonTable+";" +
                                "</script>"+
                                "<div> </div>"+
                                "</body></html>");
                        response.getWriter().close();
```

the function

```
function uploadComplete() {
    //the variable newStatement in the iframe containing the returned variable
    var stat=parent.document.newStatement;
    //assigning a variable in the general context
    var myVar=this.currentSession=stat;

}
```